# AppExchange Checkout for ISV outside the US

Tags: app, isv, appexchange

Does AppExchange Checkout already support ISVs located outside the US? I know that they are using Recurly and based on Recurly's website, they do accept Paypal Payments.

Does this mean that anybody around the world can use AppExchange Checkout as long as they have a Paypal Account?

Answer (score 3):

AppExchange checkout *does accept international credit cards*!

Paypal isn't currently accepted.

We had the same question at [Bracket Labs](http://www.bracketlabs.com) a few weeks ago when we started using.

Comment: Thanks Jordan! I'm referring to setting up something on the ISV side. Right now I think they only accept Credit Card right? It means that we'll have to get a merchant account right?

Comment: Yes, I believe that's correct.

Answer (score 3):

Per the [recurly appexchange faq](http://appexchange-docs.recurly.com/faq):

> Recurly is currently available in: Australia, Austria, Belgium, Brazil, Bulgaria, Canada, Chile, Cyprus, Czech Republic, Denmark, Egypt, Estonia, Finland, France, Germany, Gibraltar, Greece, Hong Kong, Hungary, Iceland, Ireland, Isle of Man, Israel, Italy, Latvia, Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Macau, Malaysia, Malta, Monaco, Netherlands, New Zealand, Norway, Poland, Portugal, Romania, Russia, San Mariono, Singapore, Slovenia, Sloviakia, South Africa, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland, Turkey, United Arab Emirates, United Kingdom, United States, Vatican City

That's still not 100% clear to me as to whether it's talking on the ISV side, but I am fairly certain it is since [elsewhere on recurly](https://docs.recurly.com/faq) it says "your customers may come from all over the globe."

It is very clear that you need a merchant bank account, a bit higher up the page.

Answer (score 1):

Jeremy is right regarding the available countries for Checkout provided above but you can not connect into Recurly (Salesforce Checkout) with a standard PayPal Account.

You need to be using PayPal PayFlow Pro which is a corporate gateway account and tie that into a bank merchant account.  The process is not as simple as just signing up for a standard PayPal account